# Flutter decode one column of SQLite query result

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart, encoding

My problem is that I have a sqlite Database with a column 'Rezepte'(Recipes) which contains a column 'Rezept_ID' and a column with the name('Rezept_Title') and I get a output like this:

> {Rezept_ID: 0, Rezept_Title: [84, 104, 117, 110, 102, 105, 115, 99,
> 104, 102, 105, 108, 101, 116, 32, 105, 110, 32, 90, 105, 109, 116, 45,
> 83, 101, 115, 97, 109, 45, 75, 114, 117, 115, 116, 101, 32, 97, 117,
> 102, 32, 67, 104, 105, 108, 105, 45, 77, 97, 110, 103, 111, 45, 83,
> 97, 108, 97, 116]}

But I want for example(I'm not sure what the encoding means):

> {Rezept_ID: 0, Rezept_Title: 'spaghetti'}

I found out that the numbers are just a decimal encoding and my question is:
How can I encode always just the column 'Rezept_Title'  anscii? Or is there another encoding which dart shows in cleartext?
My current function to get the recipes is:

```
getRecipes() async {
  Database db = await DatabaseHelper.instance.database;

  // get all rows
  List<Map> result = await db.query('Rezepte');

  // print the results
  return result.forEach((row) => print(row));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Rezept_Title is an array representation of a buffer instead of a string.

To make a string back out of a buffer array, use: `new String.fromCharCodes(array)`

In example:

```
getRecipes() async {
  Database db = await DatabaseHelper.instance.database;

  // get all rows
  List<Map> result = await db.query('Rezepte');

  // copy List of mutable Maps the ugly way
  List<Map> parsedResult = [];
  result.forEach((r) => parsedResult.add(Map<String, dynamic>.from(r)));
  
  // make Rezept_Title string again
  parsedResult.forEach((r) =>
    r['Rezept_Title'] = new String.fromCharCodes(r['Rezept_Title'])
  );

  // print the parsed results
  return parsedResult.forEach((row) => print(row));
}
```

You should get a print of:

```
{Rezept_ID: 0, Rezept_Title: "Thunfischfilet in Zimt-Sesam-Kruste auf Chili-Mango-Salat"}
```

---

PS: Better way to do this would be saving strings instead of buffers into database (and converting current records).

Comment: Thank you! But I am still thinking about a solution for flutter

Comment: Thank you very much but now I get a error (Unhandled Exception: Unsupported operation: read-only) I think because a database returns immutable. I looked it up but dont understand how to solve it. What I know is that I have to copy sth. I think its the data of the database do you know how to do that?

Comment: Let's try making a new List copying the immutable one's data. See my edited answer. Not sure if this would rly work, I'm not too much into Dart.

Comment: no its still the same error but still big thanks I just ask the question with another title

Comment: One more try of copying each row as a separate mutable Map. It's not very elegant, but I hope it'd work.

Comment: It works perfectly thanks for taking so much time. :D

Comment: I'm glad my first ever lines of Dart worked at last :-)